# Why a string is not nulled terminated when passing in a function?

Tags: c

This is my call:

```
testFunc(0,0,"+++++A+++b+c++++d+e++++f+g+++++h+i","Abcdefghi");
```

To the function:

```
void testFunc(int isRight, int step, const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    static int testNum = 1;
    printf("test%d: %d\n", testNum++, extendedSubStr(isRight, step, str1, str2));
}
```

That calls:

```
    int extendedSubStr(int isRight, int gap, const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
// find location of the first char
        char * pch;
        char * firstOcur;
        pch=strchr(str1,str2[0]);
        firstOcur = pch;
        int i=0;
        while (pch!=NULL)
        {
            i++;
            // find next char from the remaining string
            pch=strchr(pch+1,str2[i]);
        }

    if(i==strlen(str2))
    {
                    // return position of the first char
        return firstOcur-str1;
    }
}
```

My problem starts when i try to iterate through `str1`  using `strchr()` which expects a null terminated string. It keeps looping for some reason. I would prefer not to use `memchr()`.

Why `str1` and `str2` aren't nulled terminated? How can i terminate them?

Comment: You need to show more code. The strings will be terminated, so something else must be wrong in your program.

Comment: > Why `str1` and `str2` aren't nulled terminated? How can i terminate them? Actually, they most certainly *are* NUL terminated. Your problem lies someplace else (probably inside `extendedSubStr()`), but it's impossible to tell based on the information you've given us.

Comment: I think you need to take a closer look at `extendedSubStr()`, and/or post the code for us to look at.

Comment: @FredLarson i added more code

Comment: i added more code, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms of the problem?

Comment: Show us a complete, compilable example using the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. Showing fragments of a program leads to speculation and makes it harder to answer than needed.

Comment: @Flexo this is all the code there is

Comment: I doubt it. What I'd like to see is one single file, from `#include` to `int main()` in one code block that I can write to disk using `cat > test.c` and the compile and poke at myself. 20 people having to check to see that we need stdlib.h, string.h, stdio.h and possibly some others as well as writing a `main()` is an enormous amount of wasted effort. You'll get better answers (and automatic upvotes from me) if you always include the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem exactly.

Comment: @Flexo i will surely take that into consideration next time i post a c question. seems reasonable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two strings are definitely null terminated. **What happens is that your code iterates past the null terminators.**

You need to stop iterating when `str2[i]` reaches `\0`:

```
    int i = 1;
    while (pch != NULL && str2[i] != 0)
    {
        pch = strchr(pch + 1, str2[i++]);
    }
```

From the `strchr` manpage:

> The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string; therefore if c is `\0`,
>        the functions locate the terminating `\0`.

Basically, what happens is that once you reach the null character in `str2`, you match the null character in `str1`. After this, your loop proceed to look for characters that appear past the end of `str2` in memory that follows `str1`. Chaos ensues.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
while (pch!=NULL && *(pch+1)!='\0' && str2[i]!='\0')
```

instead of

```
while (pch!=NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, C style strings are terminated with '\0'.

You might want to look at [`strstr(s1, s2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr). strstr looks for the position of s2 in s1. Since the parameters `isRight` and `gap` aren't used, this would simplify `extendedSubStr`

```
int extendedSubStr(int isRight, int gap, const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    char *r = strstr(str1, str2);
    return r != NULL ? r - str1 : -1;
}
```